# Results of gdb on core dump from Joomla Installation - meaning?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I am still working with a resource issue for a Joomla site (currently on 3.7.0 - just upgrading to 3.7.1 as we speak). There were a lot of core dump files appearing in the home folder, thus I requested the host run them through gdb and send me the results. However, this is the first time I have ever worked with core dump files and have absolutely no idea what the results mean - or even if they are Joomla specific?

```
Report:
===================================================
Core was generated by `/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/bin/php-cgi /home/tblig0/public_html/index.php'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007efea5ce6c9a in _efree ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007efea5ce6c9a in _efree ()
#1  0x00007efea5d1bc5d in zend_hash_destroy ()
#2  0x00007efea5caaa7b in php_module_shutdown ()
#3  0x00007efea5b8a97f in main ()
==================================================
```

Can anyone help/advise on what the next step should be - what do these results mean?

Regards
D

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Joomla! it self. Joomla! has no direct access to your server memory. If there is anything like this happening in your Joomla! installation you should contact your hosting provider and figure out it with him cause this can be a possible security risk if there are memory leaks on the server. This his job to take care of this. Of course you can provide him with those dump files.

Comment: Thank you for the information, there server is constantly generating these core dump files which are obviously taking up a lot of space thus I have requested the host to look into it again - The site is hosted with LunarPages and their support is extremely poor unfortunately.

Comment: I strongly advise you to change the hosting company.